# transfer wordpress from subdomain to main domain

Tags: wordpress

i want to transfer a wordpress website in the same server from sub domain http://karanautomobiles.com/mobile to main domain http://doctormobile.co.in/...
i have the server of godaddy
previously i tried this

my wordpress website was under the link subdomain but after doing all things i wanted to shift this site to main domain/ i simply move all the files from mobile folder to main domain.. and in the database under wp_options table replace that url to main domain and also did search n replace on wp_posts table to url main domain but nothing happened please tell me how to proceed

Comment: I suggest exporting your entire db and opening it up in a code editor (notepad++) and doing a search and replace on it replacing all instances of your old domain with your new domain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow these additional steps:

```
1. Administration > Settings > General
2. change url here.
3. In site address (URL): change the address
4. Click Save Changes.
```

Let me know what happened?